# why ?ListLinePlot do not show link to help pages like other commands?

Tags: bugs, documentation

**Bug introduced in 11.0**

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any idea why `?ListLinePlot`  do not bring the standard help with that link at the end which sends one to the actual help page like other commands do?  I restarted Mathematica, and it still does not work.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But, for example, another commands, works as expected

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`ListLinePlot` is an actual command:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do others have this problem?

Comment: I see the same. I guess they just forgot to add the `ListLinePlot::usage` message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the reference, here is a screenshot of what I get with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 installed on the same system:

[image: screesnhot]

In version 11.0.1 the `ListLinePlot::usage` message is not defined:

```
ListLinePlot::usage
```

> ```
> ListLinePlot::usage
> ```